# AdView and ViewPager

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, admob, viewpagerindicator

I have Android application with ViewPager implemented like this :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6_1KznO95A

I don't know how to implement AdView below the ViewPager. I have tried to put AdView below the ViewPager programmatically and in xml. There is no errors but ads are not showing.

My xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="top"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"/>

<com.google.ads.AdView
 android:id="@+id/ad"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
 ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @GavriloPrincip please do not repost the same question. You won't increase the chances of someone answering it, but you will increase your chances of getting a warning from the higher moderation team. Besides, it pollutes the question list and it's not nice towards others. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `android:layout_weight` for a `RelativeLayout`.

Second, there is no `android:orientation` for a `RelativeLayout`.

If you want to use those, use a `LinearLayout`, not a `RelativeLayout`. If you do that, get rid of the three `android:layout_alignParent*` attributes from the `AdView`, along with `android:layout_below`, as those are for `RelativeLayout`, not `LinearLayout`.

The result should work, assuming that `AdView` works with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <com.google.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/ad"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"
   ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
   ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
  </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```